# Is there a comprehensive source for aircraft specification data for most of the aircraft in the world?

Tags: aircraft-performance, datasets

I'm aware that I can look at the Wikipedia entry for an aircraft and discover specifications like the MTOW, length, cruise speed, etc. However, I was wondering whether there is a (preferably free) source of all this data combined for most aircraft. Does such a data source exist?

Comment: Most? From Wright's flyers up? 2 seaters to A380? Russians built as well as western built and china built? Then there is too many. Can you scope down a bit of what you want?

Comment: [By MTOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airliners_by_maximum_takeoff_weight)

Comment: No scope. But I appreciate a database would be incomplete.

Comment: FWIW, there are a few weight & balance manuals for the 747 at http://terryliittschwager.com/wbmanuals.php. These manuals were supplied to me in connection with weight & balance software development and with no mention of confidentiality or proprietary.  Interestingly, the latest manual supplied to me has in prominent blue letters the word "proprietary", so I've not put that manual up.

Comment: What you want all planes specs for? Some research or personal use? If you list which plane you want to know maybe someone may have them handy but **no one** will have specs of most planes at hand.

Comment: I want to *compare* aircraft by certain specifications as an exploratory exercise. I appreciate that any list will be incomplete, but a rudimentary search hasn't come up with any. I'm interested whether someone has compiled a database already. I'm not interested in the specifications of a particular aircraft or a particular specification of all aircraft.

Comment: Try this : http://www.aircraftbluebook.com/Tools/ABB/ShowSpecifications.do mostly small aircraft though

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly the sort of data source I'm after. I'd still like to know if there are any more comprehensive data sources -- including high-capacity aircraft.

Comment: Nah. If you tell us EXACTLY what parameter you are after and what class of aircraft you are looking for that might be easier for all of us. As you can see we have all the range of professional here I would appreciate if you can specify what you want so we can help you.

Comment: This question asks for a single source, it is not "too broad".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because link-only answers are not acceptable on Stack Exchange and they are the only possible answers to this question.

Answer (score 7):

You can find a lot of information about aircraft in their Type Certificate Data Sheet that is available from the FAA or other certificating authorities. The FAA's is located [here](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/Frameset?OpenPage). It takes a bit of time to find certain things, and other things aren't included like range, or sometimes dimensions.

Comment: This isn't really what I'm after. These are multiple files, whereas I'd like a single, machine-readable source. If you like, a file where every row is an aircraft and every column is a spec.

Comment: @Hugh It is a single machine-readable source. Your computer is most likely capable of retreiving files from the internet in an automated manner.

Comment: I disagree. But thank you: this is a comprehensive, if unwieldy, source of data.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Jane's All The World's Aircraft - Cover Photo]

[Jane's All The World's Aircraft](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0710629559)

It's not free (Amazon lists it for between \$500 and \$1,000 USD) and it's not machine-readable, but yes, the data is out there.

Answer (score 2):

here is one for a few large transport aircarriers https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780340741528/appendices/data-a/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes there it. The [EUROCONTROL Aircraft Performance Database](https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/default.aspx?)